# How to keep dropdown menus showing selected option after submission?

Tags: php

In my weather forecast site, I have one dropdown menu to select  "district" and a 2nd dropdown menu to select one "city" from the selected "district".
Everything works fine but everytime I make a selection and the desired forecast is shown, both dropdown menus refresh and return to their default values that are "Select district" and "Select city").

Recently I have seen a better solution, in a national forecast site here: https://www.ipma.pt/en/otempo/prev.localidade.hora/

They have a first dropdown menu with the "main district" as default and second dropdown menu with the "capital city" as default and the foreast is immediatelly displayed. 
Only after that, user can select any other district and any city of that district to display the forecast, but menus will keep showing these last selected options and will not return to original default values.

I am a beginner and despite my efforts of trial-error sequences to achieve this solution I had to give up and ask for help.

Can someone please give me a hint on how to have my dropdown menus not to open with their default values "select district" and select city" but with values "District 1" and "City A"? And if after that, user selects "District 2" and "City C" how can I keep menus showing these values, instead of returning to "Select district" and "Select city" after the forecast is displayed? Thank you so much in advance!

Current code:

```
   <?PHP
   // array with city codes that are need in the url that will get the forecast json.
   $arr = ["31880" => "City A", 
          "31994" => "City B",
          "31937" => "City C", 
          "32046" => "City D"];

   $city = isset($_GET['city']) ? $_GET['city'] : array_keys($arr)[0];
   ?>


   <form id="dropdowns" action="">

   <!-- <label>Districts:</label>-->
        <select id="district" name="district">
            <option value="000">- Select District -</option>
        </select>

   <!-- <label>Cities:</label> -->
        <select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="000">- Select City -</option>

  </select>
  </form>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    var myJson = {
 "district": [
  {
    "name": "State 1",
    "id": "state1",
    "city": [
        {
            "name": "City A",
            "id": "31880",
        },
        {
            "name": "City B",
            "id": "31994",
        }
     ]
  },
  {
    "name": "State 2",
    "id": "state2",
    "city": [
        {
            "name": "City C",
            "id": "31937",
        },
        {
            "name": "City D",
            "id": "32046",
        }
       ]
      }
    ]
   }

  $.each(myJson.district, function (index, value) {
  $("#district").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
  });

 $('#district').on('change', function(){
 console.log($(this).val());
 for(var i = 0; i < myJson.district.length; i++)
 {
 if(myJson.district[i].id == $(this).val())
 {
 $('#city').html('<option value="000">- Select City -</option>');
 $.each(myJson.district[i].city, function (index, value) {
    $("#city").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
     });
    }
   }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the website you've sent as an example, I can tell they use ajax to make their request to update the weather table without reload the page.

If you check the tab **"Network"** from your browser (you can open it by pressing F12), when you make a change in one of the select fields, they send a request to their backend API that is responsable to get the data and send to the frontend.

[image]

This approach is made using **ajax** which doesn't require your client to reload his page to make a request your backend. I suggest you take a read [here](https://skillcrush.com/2018/04/26/what-is-ajax/) to clarify how ajax works and how ajax requests works.

Since you're using **jQuery** already, you can use it to make your ajax request, like bellow:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET", // Request method
    url: "retrieve_data.php", // Path to the file responsable to receive your request and get the data to return to the frontend
    data: {
        data: "my data" // Data to be to your backend
    }
})
```

What you basically need to do is, after changing a value in one of the selects, send the new value to your backend (using ajax) get the results related to the requested value and send back to the frontend, so your frontend be responsable to display the updated data.

To get the event when a value is changed on the select field, you can do something like this:

```
$('.your-select').on('change', function() { // An event called everytime the value in your select is changed
  var value = $(this).val(); // Here you get the value from your option, so you can send to your backend and the backend turns to be responsable to get the related data

  // Ajax callout
});
```

Doing this, you deal with both of your needs, keep the select values and change the data in the frontend.

**Other support links**:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/
- https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-ajax-for-front-end-designers--cms-25099

**For opening the select with cities and districts values**

You basically need to set a variable with the value of all districts and instead use javascript use php to loop through the districts and build the options:

```
<?php foreach($districts as $district): ?>
    <option value="<?= $district->id ?>"> <?= $district->name ?> </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The variable `$districts` should have all districts of your application and as the second select, of the cities, you must initialize it like previously with the cities from the first district of your previously array. To dynamically change it (when select of district is changed), you need to use ajax.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much @gustavo.lei for your very detailed and clear instructions and I am going to read all the documentation and follow your tips. I will let you know the results soon :-)